# Changing user status

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a logging system on my site, but I don't know how to get a user's status (online/offline). I've read more themes, but I don't understand them... can someone give me an example?

Comment: you cannot know that by php. but you can save last user's activity and determine his/her status based on that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't know if the page is close from the server, you can't check that with PHP.
You can check with javascript on client side and call your server in ajax on each events.

For exemple with Jquery :

```
<script>
$(window).unload( function () { $.get('http://exemple.com/user.php?offline=true'); } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an column `status` in your `user_info` table in database and when user logs-in then update it with 'loged-in' and when it logs out then update it with 'Logs-out'

Comment: And for when the user doesn't manually log out, add a session; and change the query when it expires.

Comment: I need to understand what the user entered on the page, and when he leave!

Comment: For that you can maintain database from server side session checking script. This way you can maintain the database for login status

Comment: @Negi Russian: For that you have to create one `login-log` table and you have to maintain that database table

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep track of the user's actions; this is what Stack Overflow does (along with "last seen" instead of "online" or "offline") and it works very nicely.

Pick a criterion:

- Requested a page
- Posted something
- Whatever else applies to your website in particular

If the user hasn't done that in the last *n* minutes, then you can assume the user is offline. I'd say a good threshold is probably 30 minutes.